# How to display item and subitem from HashMap in ListView

Tags: java, android

I would like to display item and subitem from HashMap, item would be String (borrower name), subitem double(borrower loan). It's my first android app so be understanding :)

It's my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="669dp">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editButton"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Dodaj" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sumButton"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Suma dlugow" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And backend

```
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Map<String, Double> borrowers = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    borrowers.put("John", 300.0);
    arrayList.add(String.valueOf(borrowers));

    ArrayAdapter<Borrower> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And app display only one item and it's look like {John=300.0}, i want to look like:

```
John
300.0
```

or just John \t 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is just grabbing the `String` value of the entire map. You need to iterate over the map to grab the key and value and then construct your new `String` and add it to your `List`.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : borrowers.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Double value = entry.getValue();
    arrayList.add(key + "\t" + value);
}
```